# Strange font size change depending on number of list elements in iPhone browsers

Tags: html, css, iphone

```js
var font_size_span = document.getElementById("font-size");
var li_item = document.getElementById("li-item");
font_size_span.innerHTML =
  window.getComputedStyle(font_size_span).fontSize + " and " +
  window.getComputedStyle(li_item).fontSize;
```

```html
<h1 id="font-size">Hello, world</h1>
<ul>
  <li id="li-item">First item</li>
  <li>Second item</li>
</ul>
```

When I test this code on iPhone (Safari, Firefox and Chrome), I get this strange behaviour: although the `<h1>` font size is 32px and the `<li>` font size is 16px in all cases, the relative difference of the font sizes of the two elements changes considerably depending on the number of `<li>` items in the `<ul>`.

What's happening here?

<sup>(If this is a bug in Safari, Firefox *and* Chrome for iPhone, please tell me so that I will close this question as off-topic and fill relevant bug reports. But since it happens in all of them, I don't think it is a bug, probably I'm just dumb and missing something?)</sup>

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. please take the [tour] first. Then 
read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After 
that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide 
a [repro] for debugging details. Do not use the comment option to add further information. Edit your question and isnert pictures directly in the question itself.

Comment: @tacoshy Thanks for the comment, but as I mentioned, I can't add images to the body of the question, since I have less than 10 rep. If you can, please do so for me, afterwards I will delete the comments.

Comment: I am not seeing the problem on Safari on iPad IOS14.

Comment: @AHaworth Strange. I am using iOS 15 public beta but I'm not sure that really matters, since the problem also shows up in non-Apple browsers. The screenshots above are taken in Safari though.

Comment: I think Chrome on IOS is basically on the same engine as Safari.